Using upset plot instead of a venn diagram
I am trying to use upset plot instead of a venn diagram for my thesis. I am working with proteomics data, my goal is to plot the overlap between two search engines and also the unique values using upset plot. I am struggling to feed it the correct data.
data = upset_df[[ 'peptide','onlymq', 'onlysage', 'both']]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 101565 entries, 0 to 101564
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------    --------------   ----- 
 0   peptide   101565 non-null  object
 1   onlymq    101565 non-null  bool  
 2   onlysage  101565 non-null  bool  
 3   both      101565 non-null  bool  
dtypes: bool(3), object(1)
memory usage: 1.1+ MB

I am wondering also if I can plot using multiple dfs at the same time like with venn diagram you just give it a list of peptides from different runs and it compares between them and plots everything. Thanks in advance

please correct the formatting in your question, it's quite hard to understand what is code, values and text...

Yes, you can! For this, you could use the upsetplot package (you can find the documentation here).
I assume that the dataframes you mention contains the results of the search engines. What you would need to do is simply extract from the dfs the list of identified proteins for each search engine, organise them in a dictionary and use the function from_contents() of the package. Then your data would be compatible with the package's plot() function.
Here is an example of how it would work:
import upsetplot as ups
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframes
sage = pd.DataFrame(data=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], columns=['proteins'])
mq = pd.DataFrame(data=['A', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], columns=['proteins'])

# Extract the list of identified proteins from each dataframe
data_dict = {'Sage': sage['proteins'], 'MaxQuant': mq['proteins']}

# Create multiindex df compatible with upsetplot's plot() function
transformed_data = ups.from_contents(data_dict)

# Plot the result
ups.plot(data=transformed_data)

